# C# timer interval every 30 sec. but I want run one function every 12 hours

Tags: c#, timer

I have a C # service which has an interval of 30 seconds, the service carries over 8 methods, now I want one method that at 12 o'clock in the afternoon walks and only 1 time.

thanks

Comment: If it is a service why not use Windows Scheduled Service and configure to run when you want? Instead of handling it via code, why not use what we already have or am I missing something?

Comment: Scheduling is one of those problems that sounds easy at first, but depending on your needs, quickly can turn complex (error handling, avoid duplicate firing, etc). You can look at https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/ if you want a lib that handles these things in code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
DateTime MethodsLastRunTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);

...SomeMethod () 
{
    if ((DateTime.Now.Hour == 12) && (MethodsLastRunTime < DateTime.Now))
    {
        // Do stuff  
        ....
        ....

        // Flag the method as run for today
        MethodsLastRunTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes already tried the method is now executed 120 times because the timer runs every 30 seconds.

Comment: Better using a scheduler. Quartz or windows built in one. If After execution, but still being 12, something wrong happens that causes the console app/windows service to restart, it would make it execute twice.